# Cypress e2e testing: How to call JavaScript function from a link for a .js file

Tags: javascript, function, vue.js, cypress, e2e-testing

If I am visiting or requesting a page, the page DOM contains:

```
<script src="/myassets/js/bashir.js"></script>
```

Inside this JS file, i have my JS functions like `checkFields`
How can I call this function inside a [cypress](/questions/tagged/cypress) test?

Comment: *JS functions like checkFields* - this doesn't explain anything. How exactly are they defined? If they aren't exposed to global scope, you can't call them. Even if they are, you probably shouldn't if the page doesn't use them.

Comment: Not sure how it's supposed to work, it's unclear if the function is available on global scope. Any way, in e2e testing it's not supposed to be tested directly. Test how it affects the page.